# Resolving Robot File Variables in IntelliJ while Editing

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete, pycharm, robotframework

I have a Robot Framework file referencing variables. While editing the file   the keywords are marked as "Keyword definition not found". How can I set the variables so IntelliJ and Pycharm can resolve the paths correctly?

```
Resource     ${PATH}/common.robot
Library      ${LIB}/common.py

*** Keywords ***
Get ID from Object
    Get Variable # this keyword is not found
```

Comment: Please specify what is the problem - the framework cannot resolve that keyword when the case is run; or, the editor cannot and is marking it as such? And edit the title accordingly, it is absolutely generic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can ever work, at least with the current plugins available for IntelliJ - the issue comes from the location of the libraries, it's based off a variable:

```
Library      ${LIB}/common.py
```

For a plugin to find the keywords (& offer them in autosuggest etc), it needs to parse them; but `${LIB}` is a variable, which they need to substitute with its value - which obviously they don't. And if they did, it still is a variable - in some runtime context it may get a different value than the vanilla, but the plugins cannot do these evaluations.

A solution would be to switch from variable-based to relative paths, based off the suite's location; but, that's a workaround to have the IDE help you, not a real solution.

---

As you probably can see, I'm speaking broadly, and in general - I am not saying there isn't a plugin that does that, or a future version will not do it, but at present I believe this is the case.